# "Post condition failed" error when upgrading from 8.1 to 8.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

I'm in process of upgrading sitecore from 8.1 to 8.2 and now splitting into CD and CMS but im having issue getting CD working its giving me following error.

Not able to figure out where its causing the issue,

Stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull(T result, String message)
>   +85    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name) +86    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabases() +121    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.Initialize() +105    (Object
>   , Object[] ) +117    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args) +484    (Object , Object[] ) +71
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +259
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +704
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Post condition failed]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +112    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by enabling switchMasterToWeb.config in Z.switchMasterToWeb  folder instead of switchMasterToWeb in include folder.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `DefaultFactory` and its `GetDatabases` method. This method gets all the databases which are defined inside `sitecore/databases/database` configuration.

Looks like there is still `master` database in that configuration, but you already removed its connection string or some other configuration relating to that database.

If you look at [Configure a content delivery server](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server) guide, there is information to remove `configuration/sitecore/databases/database` (Comment out the entire **master** database section).

Comment: I've already done that, it only mentioned about sitecore.buket.config

Comment: The exception is thrown **only** when sitecore cannot create a database object based on the configuration which is in `configuration/sitecore/databases/database`. Check other files. Maybe you have a patch or some extra file containing `<databases>` tag and `master` database inside it